# How can I trace a method which was inherited via polymorphism back to it's original interface?

Tags: html, vba

I asked a question this morning about how an object in VBA was successfully executing a method that was not listed under the possible methods for that object in the object library.  Thanks to user [Toby Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6244/toby-allen)  I learned that I was thinking about it all wrong.  The object in question was the IHTMLelement and the method was "getelementsbytagname", which I was referencing from the Microsoft HTML Object Library.  However, he informed me that's it's not an object at all but rather an interface, and it was inheriting members from other interfaces (hence why it wasn't showing up in the object library) and after reading about this in depth I believe I have a good grasp on it.

However, I tried to backtrack using MSDN and find out which interfance this method is really from, so I went to the [IHTMLelement help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752279(v=vs.85).aspx) which says it inherits an interface from the [IDispatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221608(v=vs.85).aspx) interface which inherits from the [IUnkown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509(v=vs.85).aspx) interface.  But still none of these list the method in question - the "getelementsbytagname" method! Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  The methods are from an interface under the ihtmlelement interface, not vice-versa.  It was actually an htmlbuttonelement